# WindowsIdentity object works on IIS Express (Visula Studio) but does not work on IIS (10)

Tags: web-services, iis, permissions, active-directory

BC users need to retrieve files from a non-cloud file store. There is a simple webservice on the storage computer that can provide contents of the files. WS gets a user name. Users exists as users on the computer/LAN, where the files are stored, so the webservice is able to check whether the user has read permission on the file or not.
WS cannot get a user password, so I cannot make any impersonation, but the webservice runs in context with privileges able to read all these documents and can check permissions by user name.
[I found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936443/get-permission-to-a-file-for-another-user-by-login-name-c-sharp), how to check file permissions by user name. Solution works well in development environment (IIS Express in Visual Studio) but fails on IIS (production environment). The problem seems to be the initialization of the WindowsIdentity object, where proces on IIS fails with the message: "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Constructor of WindowsIdentity object probably calls some AD service and some restriction in IIS it rejects.

Do you have any suggestions on what to set up in IIS or what to do to make permission checking work?

Comment: You can try this solution: [https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100049080](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100049080).

Comment: Thanks, but service still not working.. still trying.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: When I make explicit impersonation inside WS code (by WindowsIdentity.Impesonate), WindowsIdentity object used for checking if another user has file access works fine even in IIS. So there is probably some IIS context to be set, to make code work without explicit impersonation...

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Probably yes, but the solution is not as "clean" as I want and there is probably better solution...